# Outlook addin Pin add-in on desktop

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I've been create one add-in that gives support to clients when reading emails. The question is there a way to pin the add-in like the Insight add-in to keep helping the client as they open emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating an [Outlook web add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins-overview), this is possible by adding a [pinnable task pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/pinnable-taskpane) to your add-in manifest.

Please see the linked documentation for the full XML. If you already have a task pane, you can add the `SupportsPinning` element to it.

```html
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
  <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
  <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
</Action>
```

It's also important to implement a handler for the [ItemChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/pinnable-taskpane#handling-ui-updates-based-on-currently-selected-message) so your add-in can show updated information when the user selects a different message.

Answer (score 0):

While reviewing Microsoft Outlook documentation, I did not find any way to add a pin on Desktop

The only note I got from the documentation is:

```
In Outlook, click File > Manage Add-ins.

Click Manage Add-ins

In Outlook Web App, click Settings Settings > Manage add-ins.

Under Manage add-ins, in the Turned on column, select the check box for the add-in you want to enable.

Turn on or off add-ins
```

[Microsoft Outlook documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-an-add-in-on-in-outlook-for-windows-f2ec3c07-59ce-4fd4-912d-460aa0bd009d)